# Why don't Font Awesome icons show up in my anchor?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome-5

I know if my question seems strange but i found a weird behavior when using fontawesome, usually it always shows up when i'm using it and i'm already read the [Docs](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use) and some of the answer that i read in here doesn't solve my problem

source that i already try :

[FontAwesome icons not showing. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922833/fontawesome-icons-not-showing-why)

[why some of the font-awesome icons does not show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49483115/why-some-of-the-font-awesome-icons-does-not-show)

[Font awesome is not showing icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867795/font-awesome-is-not-showing-icon)

all of the answer in there doesn't solve my problem.

in stylesheet i'm using external link from fontawesome

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

This is what i want to show:

```
<div id="whatsapp-go"><a target="_blank" href="#"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a></div>

<div id="back-to-top"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i></div>
```

the only one that appear is the arrow but not with the whatsapp icon

[image of the icon doesn't show up](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-9FelvjFIc-8/XG7vP-fCsrI/AAAAAAAABdA/ex-IjXbxTukRVe_D2BE6XuJew1rfRvHcQCLcBGAs/s1600/fontawesome.PNG)

but when i'm using it in another element it shows without any problem

[Icon shows without problem](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-poJcpFJdu6U/XG7wJuY7ElI/AAAAAAAABdI/kxMo0e0s2wEH9sgSNrQpk6D9HZegE7RPgCLcBGAs/s320/fontawesome-2.PNG)

here the code that the icon shows up :

```
<ul class="footer-follow">
    <li>
        <a class="icon-color btn-floating btn-sm mx-1" target="_blank" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-square fa-2x" alt="#"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="icon-color btn-floating btn-sm mx-1" target="_blank" href="#"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp fa-2x"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="icon-color btn-floating btn-sm mx-1" target="_blank" href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"> </i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="icon-color btn-floating btn-sm mx-1" target="_blank" href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="icon-color btn-floating btn-sm mx-1" target="_blank" href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube fa-2x"></i></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

can someone help me in this?

CSS file :

```
/*------------------------------------*\
    Back to top
\*------------------------------------*/

#back-to-top {
    display:block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #0bb89e;
    border-radius:50px;
    color: #FFF;
    z-index: 9999;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s opacity;
    transition: 0.2s opacity;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#back-to-top:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}


/*------------------------------------*\
    Whatsapp-go
\*------------------------------------*/

#whatsapp-go {
    display:block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 80px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #0bb89e;
    border-radius:50px;
    color: #FFF;
    z-index: 9999;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s opacity;
    transition: 0.2s opacity;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#whatsapp-go:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: Obviously the library is loading, and your syntax appears correct. You'll need to create a full demo so we can investigate.

Comment: Can you provide the full code of your css? Something's wrong there.

Comment: I'd start with your anchor text color. Maybe the icon is there but it matches the background. You should be able to verify with your browser's document inspector.

Comment: I adding the demo site in the post

Comment: I adding the CSS for the back-to-top and the whatsapp-go

Comment: This is because the background color of the circle & link-color are same #0bb89e. Change the color of the link (a) tag. The icon is almost there.

Comment: You are right, it my fault that i'm forget about the color of my external link, thankyou very much it solved my problem ^.^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's there it's just that the whatsapp icon is a child of the `<a>` tag and links are set to the same green as the background:

[image]

Set the font color to be white.

```
#whatsapp-go a {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much! it's my fault that i'm forget about the color of the external link, seems like it is not the problem with the fontawesome itself