# Why some of the FontAwesome icons are not showing?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I'm trying to create a social sharing module in my Java web application. I'm using this example from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_social_bar.asp).
I already had fontawesome icons in the project but for some reason after adding the following code only either of them (social icons or old icons in the site) are working. They are showing square icons or no icons on switching with various cdn links of fontawesome css.

```html
     <link
 rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pure/1.0.1/pure-min.css"
 crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Load font awesome icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- The social media icon bar -->
    <div class="icon-bar">
      <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="google"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
      <i class='fa fa-brain'></i>          
      <i class='fa fa-calculator'></i>          
    </div>
```

I've not added the css code from the example though. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your code snippet is working. Which fontawesome' version are you using in your web?

Comment: I've tried with 4.7.0, 5.12.1 etc. None of the version can make both the thing work.

Comment: in 5x `fa fa-google` may not work. check there official website. They updated classes.

Comment: I'm not trying fa5 or anything. Just plain icon

Comment: of you are using 4x, the example you shared is working fine.

Comment: did you add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">` in your website header ?

Comment: this file `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pure/1.0.1/pure-min.css` didn't contain any fontawesome css

Comment: Add <i class='fa fa-calculator' style='font-size: 48px; color: #338bb7'></i><i class='fa fa-brain'></i>. The icon for brain will not show.

Comment: brain icon is not in version 4, you need to use fa5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208413/discussion-between-v0ld3m0rt-and-waqas-mumtaz).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why some of the font-awesome icons does not show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49483115/why-some-of-the-font-awesome-icons-does-not-show)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using few icons from fontawesome 5. for example `fa-brain`. You need to update css link and font classes accordingly.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/js/all.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Load font awesome icons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css">

<!-- The social media icon bar -->
<div class="icon-bar">
  <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="google"><i class="fab fa-google"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="youtube"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="calculator"><i class="fas fa-calculator"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="brain"><i class="fas fa-brain"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to use only icons from the free set if you do not have a pro license. https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&m=free

Answer (score -1):

The icons are working fine.

```
<link
rel="stylesheet"
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pure/1.0.1/pure-min.css"
crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Load font awesome icons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- The social media icon bar -->
<div class="icon-bar">
  <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="google"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
</div>
```

Check Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/YzXNNLw

There is some another variability in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But now add <i class='fa fa-calculator' style='font-size: 48px; color: #338bb7'></i><i class='fa fa-brain'></i>. The icon for brain will not show.

Comment: `<i class='fa fa-brain'></i>` Does not appear because there is no such class `font-awesome 4.7.0`. Brain icon came in later versions. Try to downloading SVG or in font format. Otherwise use upgraded versions.